# How to Generate Registration number(UserId) and send it in mail to user after user has registered?

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0

A part of my web application register users and sends a confirmation mail to them after storing their data in a database. How can i assign **each user a unique registration ID** automatically like of  this pattern **"MVIN-0000001"** and so on for each user

```
//Inserting registration data of user!!!
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
string inscmd = "Insert into Registration(Username, Password,EmailAddress,FullName,CNIC,city) Values(@UserName, @Password, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @CNIC, @City)";
SqlCommand InsertUser = new SqlCommand(inscmd, con);
InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBoxUN.Text);
InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBoxPass.Text);
InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", TextBoxEA.Text);
InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBoxFN.Text);
InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNIC", TextBoxCNIC.Text);
InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.ToString());

try
{
    con.Open();
    //Response.Write("Trying ...");
    InsertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
    Response.Write("Failed!!! ...");
    Response.Write("<b>Something really bad happened .. try again later</b>");
}

//send mail message after user fills registration form 
try                
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("motionvotersys@gmail.com");
    msg.To.Add(TextBoxEA.Text);
    msg.Subject = "Your Registration is confirmed! ";
    msg.Body = "Dear " + TextBoxFN.Text + " Your Registration to motion voter system has been confirmed. .. Kindly note down your Voter's Identity Number(VIN) required for your login";
    SmtpClient Sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    Sc.Port = 587;
    Sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("motionvotersys@gmail.com","password");
    Sc.EnableSsl = true;
    Sc.Send(msg);
    Response.Write("Sent!!! ... ");
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

i want to add the VIN (Id#) in my **msg.Body** statement, how can i do that? 
as one of the member hav already suggested me to use the UserID column  of table to generate the Registration Numbers **BUT**
... i am not learning SQL at present. i m just learning c# and asp.net, but a part of my project tat i have selected deals with Databases ... the UserId column in my database table is **PrimarKey** ... it gets incremented itself along with the user info in other columns whenever a user registers. Can some one Pleaseeeee tell me how can i use this UserId column to **get** its value and store it in a normal integer variable?? Please help. –

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to store their data in the database?

Comment: @Robbie: I have added the code i m using to store user info above. Kindly review the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the newly inserted ID of the user as an output parameter and concatenate your "MVIN" prefix (plus padding zeros) with that ID.

```
-- after insert
SET @NewId = scope_identity();
```

Personally I don't like exposing database IDs in that fashion. I would rather use a crytographically random number so that there is less of a chance that a user can extrapolate another legitimate number. For example, if my ID is "MVIN-0005", it's a pretty simple step to try "MVIN-0004" and "MVIN-0006".

```
internal static long CreateId()
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider _crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    _crypto.GetBytes( bytes );
    return BitConverter.ToInt64( bytes, 0 );
}
```

The resulting IDs will be quite large (perhaps too much for a user to type?). You can shorten the number by zeroing out bytes at the end of the array (`bytes[6] = bytes[7] = 0;`)

Since there is no guarantee that two random numbers generated in this fashion won't collide, storing them along with the user record may also be a necessity (so that you can check for dupes).

Comment: sir, To tell u the truth ... i am not learning SQL at present. i m just learning c# and asp.net, but a part of my project tat i have selected deals with Databases ... the UserId column in my database table is PrimarKey ... it gets incremented itself along with the user info in other columns whenever a user registers. Can you Pleaseeeee tell me how can i use this UserId column to **get** its value and store it in a normal integer variable?? Please help. –